# Get from 8th string character to last string character

Tags: c#, string

So my school project is :

String s1 = **Hrvatska** ima more

string s2 = Italija **je prvak svijeta**

string s3 = **Hrvatska je prvak svijeta**

```
        string s1 = "Hrvatska ima more";
        string s2 = "Italija je prvak svijeta";
        string s3 = s1.Substring(0, 8);
              s3 += s2.Substring(7, s2.Length);    (ERROR LINE)

        Console.WriteLine(s3);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

ERROR: 
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length'

... and i do not have any idea how to fix this problem :/

Comment: Best idea: read the docs. Put the cursor on `.Substring` and hit F1.  The documentation explains what each parameter means and the various overloads

Comment: @cptwonton Except that the second argument to `Substring` is the length, not the end index.

Comment: I am a fool and thought this was a Java substring question. You are correct @juharr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use

```
s2.Substring(7);
```

And it will take a substring starting from `7` index including 7th char.

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a
>   specified character position and continues to the end of the string.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto the 7th char is ` ` so OP needs it to correctly display space between words

Answer (score -1):

Substring() - Second argument is how many characters to cut not index.
This will work:

```
s3 += s2.Substring(7, s2.Length - 7);
```

Comment: No need for the second argument. The default is to read to the end